# Compacting multiple promises

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have the following JavaScript promise chain. It works as expected.

```
signUp (data) {
  return oneFunction(username).then((usernameExist) => {
    return firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password).then((user) => {
      firebaseDb.ref('users/' + user.uid + '/public/').set(userData).then()
      utils.updateUsernameMapping(data.username, user.uid).then()
      return user.updateProfile({
        displayName: data.displayName
      }).then(function () {
        return user
      }, error => {
         throw error
      })
    })
  }).catch(error => {
    throw error
  })
}
```

However, I believe the **signUp** function is hard to decipher because of the nested levels. I tried to change it to the following approach:

```
userPromise
.then()
.then()
.then();
```

But I couldn't get it working because the user variable needs to be passed down the chain. Ideally, I would like to minimize this code for readability and use one **catch()** for efficiency. Any ideas appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Following feedback from Bergi, below is my updated code:

```
signUp (email, password, displayName, username) {
  const userData = { username: username, lastLogin: Firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP }
  return utils.checkIfUserExists(username).then(usernameExist => {
    return firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  }).then(user => {
    return Promise.all([
      firebaseDb.ref('users/' + user.uid + '/public/').set(userData),
      utils.updateUsernameMapping(username, user.uid),
      user.updateProfile({displayName})
    ]).then(() => user)
  })
},
```

Comment: I don't think `error => {
        return error
      }` works as you'd expect. And why are you calling `.then();` without arguments on `firebase.ref…` and `utils.updateUsernameMapping…`?!

Comment: Just declare a var higher up the scope chain and assign it on the first call. Or if your a stickler, return it in an array with the other value and use destructuring to access it.

Comment: Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35805818/7564182) for clarification on promise chaining...

Comment: @JaredSmith No, don't do that.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi I edited the post.

Answer (score 2):

Error handlers that just rethrow the error are pointless, omit them.

You can [unnest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572) the outermost level with the `usernameExist` variable that you don't need anywhere else:

```
signUp (data) {
  return oneFunction(username).then(usernameExist => {
    return firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }).then(user => {
    return Promise.all([
      firebaseDb.ref('users/' + user.uid + '/public/').set(userData),
      utils.updateUsernameMapping(username, user.uid),
      user.updateProfile({displayName})
    ]).then(() => user);
  });
}
```

There's nothing wrong with the nested `then` that ensures that `user` is returned in the end. There are [a few approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572) to tackle this problem, nesting closures is just fine.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. This is exactly what I was looking for as looks a lot neater. I'll repost your answer with a few minor modifications.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple promises use

`p1 = new Promise();
p2 = new Promise();
p3 = new Promise();
Promise.all([p1, p2, p3])`

[Promise.all documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about how to thread a value through a promise chain.

Comment: I don't think the OP's promises are independent of each other, though.