# Promises miss understand

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, promise

Hi i have simple code like that:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function Item(val) {
        this.val = val
        var self = this;
        this.generateTrDOM = function () {
            var tr = '<tr>';
            tr += '<td>' + self.val + '</td>';
            tr += '</tr>';
            return tr;
        };
    }

    function ItemsCollection() {
        this.someHandler = $('#some_table_id');
        this.data = [];
        var self = this;


        this.getData = function () {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                $.post(base_url + 'controller/action', {
                    action_type: 'get_items'
                }, function (data) {
                    self.prepareData(data).then(resolve());
                }, "json");
            });
        };
        this.prepareData = function (data) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    self.data.push(
                        new Item(data[x])
                    );
                }
            });
        };
        this.updateTable = function () {
            for (var x = 0; x < self.data.length; x++) {
                self.someHandler.append(self.data[x].generateTrDOM());
            }

        };
    }

    var data = new ItemsCollection();
    data.getData() //this is done second
        .then(
            data.updateTable(); //this is done first - i dont not want to
        );
});
```

I want to **data.updateTable()** took place after the **data.getData()** after AJAX request but its start before. I read about the promises and in my other project its worked very well.

Which I did not understand. Thanks for some advices.

Comment: There are a number of anti-patterns here, but very quickly, change this: `self.prepareData(data).then(resolve());` to this `self.prepareData(data).then(resolve);`  You need to pass a function reference, not the result of executing the function.

Comment: Probably you just want to do `return $.post(...)` and not wrap it in another promise.  `$.post()` already returns a promise.

Comment: Thx. Can u tell some keywords to percive anti-patters? :D

Comment: In your Items class in the generate dom method your are using this and probably forgot to self = this, that is why your table could be empty, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Laurens Mäkel with setTimeout() its works very well. I give only very simple skeleton of this app

Comment: in `this.prepareData` , shouldn't it be resolved after the loop ?

Comment: @jfirend00 self.prepareData(data).then(resolve); nothing change

Comment: @Taki this.prepareData nothing change :/

Comment: That's because there are lots of other problems.  `prepareData()` doesn't resolve its promise.  In fact, it's not even asynchronous so it doesn't need to use a promise at all.

Comment: Lots of articles on promise anti-patterns [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=promise+anti+patterns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix the problem. As jfriend00 said, you have to pass a function reference to then(..). If you pass data.updateTable() to then(..) the function is executed immediately.

```
var data = new ItemsCollection();
data.getData()
  .then(data.updateTable);
```

Answer (score 1):

try to avoid nested promises to keep your async code linear.

check this post : [Are nested promises normal in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805603/are-nested-promises-normal-in-node-js) ( i know this is not node but it's the same idea :P )

and to do so, you'll need to call `getData`, resolve it, then call `prepareData` and resolve it , then `updateTable` like :

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function Item(val) {
        this.val = val
        var self = this;
        this.generateTrDOM = function () {
            var tr = '<tr>';
            tr += '<td>' + self.val + '</td>';
            tr += '</tr>';
            return tr;
        };
    }

    function ItemsCollection() {
        this.someHandler = $('#some_table_id');
        this.data = [];
        var self = this;


        this.getData = function () {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                $.post(base_url + 'controller/action', {
                    action_type: 'get_items'
                }, function (data) {
                    resolve(data); 
                }, "json");
            });
        };

        this.prepareData = function (data) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    self.data.push(
                        new Item(data[x])
                    );
                }               
                resolve(self.data);
            });
        };

        this.updateTable = function (data) {
            for (var x = 0; x < self.data.length; x++) {
                self.someHandler.append(data[x].generateTrDOM());
            }
        };
    }

    var data = new ItemsCollection();

    data.getData()
        .then((result) => {
            return data.prepareData(result);            
        })  
        .then((prearedData) => {
            return data.updateTable(prearedData); 
        });
});
```

here's a working fiddle for that https://jsfiddle.net/aejvsxke/5/ ( i replaced your `$post` with a `$.get` 
 to a fake api and added `console.log` in each function for testing purposes, so you can see the order of the execution )

use this to compare the two codes and see the differences : https://www.diffchecker.com/diff

hint : for `this.getData` you can return the `$.post` directly as it returns a promise itself (no need to wrapp it in a promise and no need for the callback ) as of **jQuery 1.5** : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

so it becomes like this :

```
this.getData = function () {
    return $.post(base_url + 'controller/action', {
                action_type: 'get_items'        
            }, "json"); 
};
```

i hope this `re`solves your problem ;) or at least gives you an idea :P